# How to apply my template in XAML button style while keeping background color?

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

I have the following style in a `Styles.xaml` file:

```
<Style x:Key="MainViewButton" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <SymbolIcon Symbol="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="#FFF7F7F7" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF55677F"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
</Style>
```

When I launch my project, the template is applied, as the buttons contain their `Content` SymbolIcon, but they don't have any background color even thought it is specified in the style after the template. They just are transparent. How come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your control template overrides any styles you set. If your `ControlTemplate` does not respect the styles, you don't get anything you set.

You can put the Setters for background and others above the Template setter and then use `TemplateBinding` to set the properties inside your `SymbolIcon`. If your SymbolIcon does not have any background property, alas, you can't do it.

You can, however, use a Border and put SymbolIconIn it. Here's how I would do it:

```
<Style x:Key="MainViewButton" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF55677F"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}">
                    <SymbolIcon Symbol="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="#FFF7F7F7" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

</Style>
```

Comment: Thank you. Just figured out I didn't really understand how ControlTemplates worked, and that they override my button and replace it with just the SymbolIcon.